# Clicking Todo on top causes bottom todo to be also clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: Before clicking todo 1]

[image: After clicking todo 1]

When I click the checkbox for Task 1 in active todo filter mode, it also toggles the checkbox for Task 2 for some reason. But if I switch between the completed todo button and come back to active todo button it goes away.

Code Sandbox
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d3n8dv?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `TodoItem` component, you need to have `checked` field in your `input` checkbox instead of `defaultChecked` field. And change `onClick` to `onChange` as well.

```
      <span>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={props.isActive}
          onChange={() => props.checkBoxHandler(props.todoItem)}
        />
        {props.todoItem}
      </span>
```

Comment: That did fix it, but can you tell me why that happened, I am still not sure of the reasoning behind why this worked and the earlier one did not. The issue seems to have been the defaultchecked but still unsure as to why.

Comment: It feels like due to the use of `defaultChecked` field, your `TodoItem` checkbox hasn't been updated for the task 2 when re-rendering after clicking on  task 1. It remains same as the task 1. `defaultChecked` is only necessary for the initial rendering of the component and not for re-rendering. Therefore, I believe that's why react didn't update the checkbox for task 2. In order to update it, you need to use `checked` field which will be updated when re-rendering.

Comment: And also, you told that it worked when going to completed view and then coming back to active view. It worked because, react will remove the `activeTodosJSX` component and place the `CompletedTodosJSX` component. When you coming back, react will mount `activeTodosJSX` again which will cause component mounting (Then `defaultChecked` will work becuase component mounting can be identified as a initial rendering event)